# Compute the compression ratio by using Huffman encoding

Tags: c, algorithm, compression, huffman-code, lossless-compression

I am trying to compute the compression ratio in this way

1- compute the original size in byte:

```
int size= sizeof(inputarr)/sizeof(inputarr[0]);
 originalsize = size *(sizeof(int))
```

2-Compute the encoded data size for Huffman in this way as I read on google (the values just for example):

```
value:1 freq : 3
value:2 freq : 4
value:3 freq : 3  
(1 * 3) + (2 * 4) + (3 * 4) 
int encodedsize = 3+ 8 + 12  = () bits/8 = ~() bytes.
```

3- the compression ratio should be:

CR =  original size /encoded size

This is my input data:

> 86,
> 5,
> 81,
> 6,
> 85,
> 14,
> 89,
> 17,
> 84,
> 6,
> 88,
> 4,
> 83,
> 4,
> 87,
> 4,
> 91,
> 2,
> 95,
> 21,
> 99,
> 8,
> 103,
> 11,
> 98,
> 4,
> 93,
> 2,
> 97,
> 11,
> 92,
> 4,
> 83,
> 4,
> 87,
> 4,
> 91,
> 20,
> 86,
> 5,
> 90,
> 4,
> 85,
> 6,
> 89,
> 14,
> 84,
> 4,
> 88,
> 4,
> 92,
> 7,
> 87,
> 14,
> 82,
> 6,
> 86,
> 2,
> 90,
> 84,
> 94,
> 6,
> 89,
> 11,
> 93,
> 6,
> 88,
> 8,
> 92,
> 20,
> 96,
> 5,
> 91,
> 16,
> 86,
> 3,
> 90,
> 28,
> 94,
> 8,
> 89,
> 10,
> 93,
> 7,
> 88,
> 12,
> 83,
> 2,
> 87,
> 8,
> 82,
> 2,
> 86,
> 6,
> 90,
> 12,
> 94,
> 29,
> 98,
> 10,
> 93,
> 2,
> 88,
> 7,
> 92,
> 49,
> 96,
> 16,
> 91,
> 8,
> 95,
> 9,
> 90,
> 2,
> 94,
> 8,
> 98,
> 8,
> 93,
> 6,
> 97,
> 31,
> 92,
> 5,
> 96,
> 48,
> 91,
> 7,
> 95,
> 15,
> 99,
> 6,
> 94,
> 8,
> 98,
> 26,
> 93,
> 8,
> 97,
> 21,
> 92,
> 9,
> 96,
> 37,
> 100,
> 24,
> 95,
> 4,
> 99,
> 35,
> 94,
> 4,
> 89,
> 6,
> 93,
> 2,
> 97,
> 23,
> 92,
> 17,
> 96,
> 20,
> 100,
> 19,

This is the values and the frequency that I got from Huffman:
Values:

> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> 11
> 12
> 14
> 15
> 16
> 17
> 19
> 20
> 21
> 23
> 24
> 26
> 28
> 29
> 31
> 35
> 37
> 48
> 49
> 81
> 82
> 83
> 84
> 85
> 86
> 87
> 88
> 89
> 90
> 91
> 92
> 93
> 94
> 95
> 96
> 97
> 98
> 99
> 100
> 103

Frequency:

> 8
> 1
> 12
> 4
> 10
> 4
> 9
> 2
> 2
> 3
> 2
> 3
> 1
> 2
> 2
> 1
> 3
> 2
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 3
> 2
> 5
> 4
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 5
> 7
> 7
> 6
> 4
> 5
> 4
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 1

The summation of

```
(value * frequency =  8499 bit ---> 8499/8 = 1062.375 byte
```

The problem that I have in this way is that: the size of encoded data is higher than the size of input data(originalsize) that should be

```
(number of values * sizeof(int)) = 164*4 = 656 byte
```

In this way the CR = 656  / 1062.375 !!
Where is the error that I have please?

UPDATE:
This is the compressed data, when I use the decompression function, I can get on the original values, but how can I represent it in a file to get smaller size than the original file(that has the original values)?
Any Idea please?

> 0111100000010010110101000001011111001010110111100011010100111101100001110100001110110001001111111101000010111001100101000101100000111101111000011001001011001110111011000011101000011101100011100000111100000010111101100000101010010101111110001110110011110111101000100000110111100101010100111100110101111000111001101010010101100111001010100110110111011100000111000000100010010110111111111000010111111010111001011010010010001111000001010011010101100001001100001011000101000110111110100101101010111001111100100001101000111100001110011000101110101001000111000101110001011011111111110110101100111100101100001101101110010100010011111010111010000001110010011010001000101111111111100110111010101100101100001111110011111000110001000100001110111110110111011111011111100011110100111111110110111001001111100111011001010101110000110010010110101110110110110111011000011110000101001

Comment: Does there have to be an error? Sometimes Huffman compression results in a larger file. This can occur when the characters in the message do not reflect the same frequency distribution as the corpus from which the Huffman table was created.

Comment: Your decompression function _cannot_ give you the original values from those ones and zeros without additional information. Those ones and zeros do not contain any information about the Huffman code. You are cheating, where your decompression function is getting that information from the compression function — not from the those ones and zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the frequency of a symbol by the symbol itself makes no sense.

There appears to be no application of Huffman's algorithm in your question. You are determining how many times each symbol occurs, which is the *input* to Huffman's algorithm. The *output* would provide the number of bits for each symbol. You would then multiply the number of bits for each symbol by the frequency, i.e. number of occurrences, of each symbol, and sum that. That gives you the total number of bits in the encoded data.

Except that you need to then add the number of bits required to *represent* the Huffman code that was generated. The decoder would need that to make any sense of the encoded symbols.

This particular data would give about 109 bytes of encoded symbols, which is less than the 164 bytes of original data, assuming it is stored as eight bits each. Though that data could be stored in seven bits for each symbol, in which case it would be 144 bytes uncompressed.

However a simple tree representation of the Huffman code is about 63 bytes, bringing the total to 172 bytes. That is larger than the original data. A more efficient representation used by deflate can do it with 33 bytes, bringing the total to 142 bytes. A little less than the original 164 bytes, and a smidge less than the 144 bytes needed if seven bits per symbol were used in the uncompressed representation.

A representation of the Huffman code is required for decompression, and an efficient one is needed to compute a realistic compression ratio. When computing a compression ratio, the representation of the original uncompressed data is also important.

To answer the update: you put eight bits in each byte. Then those 865 bits will take 109 bytes. However those bits are *not* sufficient to reconstruct the original data. They do not contain a description of the Huffman code for the decoder.

Comment: if I saved the compressed data in a file and then compute the size of original data and the size of compressed data in byte or KB is that will be correct? how can I represent the compressed data inside the file?

Comment: Yes. As bits. However there is no evidence in your question that you have even done any Huffman coding. Note that the claim that the data has been compressed can only be substantiated by writing a decompressor and decompressing back to exactly the original data using only that compressed data.

Comment: could you check the UPDATE  please?